RabbitMQ consumer issue : reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms
I have a PROD issue in a springboot camel application. I see the following errors in the log randomly

com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler |
com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler |
com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: channel is already closed
due to channel error; protocol method:
#method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - delivery acknowledgement on channel 1 timed out. Timeout value used: 1800000 ms. This timeout value can be configured, see consumers doc
guide to learn more, class-id=0, method-id=0)

The microservice is a spring boot camel application. And 2 consumers are running but only one consumer will be active at a time as we have used the following config in the RabbitMQ URL prefetchCount=1&acknowledgeMode=MANUAL&exclusive=true
Here we send a manual ACK:
final Channel channel = exchange.getProperty(SpringRabbitMQConstants.CHANNEL, Channel.class);
final long deliveryTag = exchange.getMessage().getHeader(SpringRabbitMQConstants.DELIVERY_TAG, long.class);
channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);

I tried to recreate the issue by having a consumer_timeout to a lower value and waiting before sending the ACK. But I get a different error like java.lang.IllegalStateException: Channel closed; cannot ack/nack
Could someone please let me know how to reproduce the issue locally and the fix for the issue?
